# Count of 300 non-null columns in each row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table that contains more than 300 columns. Each column is of different type. I want the count of non-null columns of that table. Since the columns are more than 300, i should not type all the column names.

For example:

```
 Column Id  |  Column1   |  Column2 | Column3 |   Column4  
------------+------------+----------+---------+-------------
   1        |    123     |    abc   |   NULL  |  Empty-space
```

Result:

```
ID | (Non-null)Column-Count
---+-----------------------   
1  |           2
```

What is the best way to get the count and also to avoid the count of columns with empty spaces?

Comment: Does your table only have 1 row? If not, add some more sample data - and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: @jarlh I can have many rows. I need to go by each row and get count of non null columns.

Comment: While this might make for an interesting SQL challenge, I cannot imagine any practical use.  Once you get the desired result, what in the world will you do with it?  This strongly suggests you are trying to solve an x-y problem.  https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` or `NVL2` combined with `TRIM`:

```sql
SELECT   CASE WHEN TRIM( column1 ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       + CASE WHEN TRIM( column2 ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       + CASE WHEN TRIM( column3 ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       + CASE WHEN TRIM( column4 ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
       ...
       or
       ...
       + NVL2( TRIM( column5 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( column6 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( column7 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( column8 ), 1, 0 )
```

*(Note, if some columns have a non-string data-type then you can remove the call to `TRIM` for that column and just use `CASE` or `NVL` directly on the column.)*

---

## Update

You can use a PL/SQL program to generate the SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql CLOB;
  v_table_name VARCHAR2(20) := 'TABLE_NAME';
BEGIN
  FOR col IN ( SELECT column_name, data_type
               FROM   user_tab_columns
               WHERE  table_name = v_table_name
               ORDER BY column_id )
  LOOP
    IF v_sql IS NULL THEN
      v_sql := 'SELECT ';
    ELSE
      v_sql := v_sql || CHR(10) || '       + ';
    END IF;
    IF col.data_type IN ( 'CHAR', 'VARCHAR2' ) THEN
      v_sql := v_sql || 'NVL2( TRIM( ' || col.column_name || ' ), 1, 0 )';
    ELSE
      v_sql := v_sql || 'NVL2( ' || col.column_name || ', 1, 0 )';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  v_sql := v_sql || ' as cnt' || CHR(10) || 'FROM   ' || v_table_name || ';';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_sql );
END;
/
```

Which for an example table with 30 columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col001 VARCHAR2(20) );

BEGIN
  FOR i IN 2 .. 30 LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE table_name ADD ( col' || TO_CHAR(i, 'FM000' )
                      || CASE MOD(i,3) WHEN 0 THEN ' NUMBER' ELSE ' VARCHAR2(20)' END
                      || ' )';
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

```sql
SELECT NVL2( TRIM( COL001 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL002 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL003, 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL004 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL005 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL006, 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL007 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL008 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL009, 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL010 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL011 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL012, 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL013 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL014 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL015, 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL016 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL017 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL018, 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL019 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL020 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL021, 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL022 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL023 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL024, 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL025 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL026 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL027, 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL028 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( TRIM( COL029 ), 1, 0 )
       + NVL2( COL030, 1, 0 ) as cnt
FROM   TABLE_NAME;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d65bbca0bb127a3d4dafb430c8912d48)*

Comment: I have almost 300+ columns. Any alternative way to go through all columns without having to write all column names?

Comment: You can write a program to generate this SQL statement.

Comment: @Sandeep Updated.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you!. This helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

This isn't fun, but something like this:

```
select ((case when column1 <> ' ' then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when column2 <> ' ' then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .
        (case when column300 <> ' ' then 1 else 0 end)
       )
```

Comment: This way i need to manually type all the columns. Can you suggest some alternative ways using All_Tab_columns??

Comment: @Sandeep . . . That requires dynamic SQL which is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SYS_REFCURSOR` in order to dynamically count by first creating a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Count_Of_NonNulls RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_tab       VARCHAR2(32) := 'MY_TABLE';
BEGIN
  SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, 'NVL2('||column_name||',1,0)' , '+')
        .EXTRACT('//text()'))
        .GetClobVal(),'+')
    INTO v_cols
    FROM ( SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = v_tab ); 

  v_sql := 'SELECT ID, '||v_cols||' FROM '|| v_tab;

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

*where the column constructing the string `v_cols` might be replaced with

`LISTAGG( 'NVL2('||column_name||',1,0)' , '+' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY column_id )`
for tables with not so many number of columns*

and then invoke

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Count_Of_NonNulls;
PRINT rc
```

from SQL Developer's Command line in order to get the result set.

The <kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=271a8c73b9a25b63789e2b34ba56ac3a)</kbd> in order to produce the SQL and the results

*P.S. `ID` is also included in the total values as being non-null column. If it should be excluded, then the subquery within the function should be replaced with `SELECT * FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = v_tab AND column_name != 'ID'`*